# How to delete margins of footer and header after implemented video background?

Tags: css, html

I implemented my video as a background on my html project, but some margins appeared on the right side of the header and footer. I searched on google and it said that i have to put "margin: 0" on my Body in CSS. I did that and it still goes on.

Image link - You can see it up in the right corner of the header.

[image]

I want to mention that on my other pages I don't have this problem. Only on this one, after i implemented that video.

```css
.homepage_bg_video-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
}

.homepage_bg_video-container video{
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#rights{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.9);
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    color: #ece5ea;
    border-top: #070606 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage_bg_video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</div>

<footer>
    <div id="rights">
        <p>Nits.SRL - Toate drepturile rezervate &copy; 2019</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the object-position property to adjust the positioning of the video within the element's frame, and the object-fit property to control how the video's size is adjusted to fit within the frame:

```
video { object-fit: fill; }
```

Hope that solve it.
Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

EDIT

try this:

```css
    body {margin: 0;}
    .homepage_bg_video-container {
        position: relative;
        max-height: 100vh;
        max-width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;    
        background-color: black;
    }
    video { 
     height: calc(100% - 62px); 
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: fill; 
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    #rights {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.9);
        height: 60px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        color: #ece5ea;
        border-top: #070606 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="homepage_bg_video-container">
        <video autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <div id="rights">
            <p>Nits.SRL - Toate drepturile rezervate &copy; 2019</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: It might be your min-width. Try comment out your css and apply it once in a time. Try object-fit first.